# pandas - get a fraction of each multi-index level label rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an XY problem. My setup is as follows - I have a dataframe with multi-index of 2 levels. I want to split it to two dataframes, taking only a fraction of rows from each label in the first level. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'b': np.random.randint(0, 100, 13), 'c':np.random.randint(0, 100, 13)}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
df
Out[13]: 
        c
a  b     
1  86  83
   1   37
   57  64
   53   5
7  4   66
   13  49
10 61   0
   32  84
   97  59
   69  98
   25  52
   17  31
   37  95
```

So let's say the fraction is 0.5, I want to split it to two dataframes:

```
        c
a  b     
1  86  83
   1   37
7  4   66
10 61   0
   32  84
   97  59
   69  98

        c
a  b     
1  57  64
   53   5
7  13  49
10 25  52
   17  31
   37  95
```

I thought about doing `(df.groupby(level = 0).count() * 0.5).astype(int)` to get the limit on which to "slice" the dataframe. Then, if only I had a way to add a running distance such as this:

```
        c  r
a  b        
1  38  36  0
   6   47  1
   57   6  2
   55  45  3
7  7   51  0
   90  96  1
10 59  75  0
   27  16  1
   58   7  2
   79  51  3
   58  77  4
   63  48  5
   87  60  6
```

I could join the limits and this df and filter with a boolean condition. Any suggestions on either problem? (splitting a fraction of rows or adding a level-aware running index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be pretty trivial with groupby:

```
In [36]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.head(int(x.shape[0] * 0.5))).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[36]: 
        c
a  b     
1  86  83
   1   37
7  4   66
10 61   0
   32  84
   97  59
```

Also getting the running index per group:

```
In [33]: df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
Out[33]: 
a   b 
1   38    0
    6     1
    57    2
    55    3
7   7     0
    90    1
10  59    0
    27    1
    58    2
    79    3
    58    4
    63    5
    87    6
```